# SSRS Drill Through using multiple values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to add a drill though from my main SSRS report into a detail report and cannot figure out how to pass multiple values.  The report looks something like this...

Loc  Tech   #ofCalls

1         Bill         23

1         Jim          20

The # of calls is a count of the individual call records.  I want to provide a drill through into a report I have that displays the details of each of the calls.  I need to pass the multiple CallId's for that technician and location into the subreport when the user clicks on the # of calls.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Drill through reports and subreports aren't the same thing. Subreports get the data at the same time as the main report, while a drill through report links to a completely separate report once the user clicks a link, button or image, and retrieves the data.

It sounds like a better approach, would be to create a separate report, that would accept perhaps a Loc and Tech parameter, and returns all of the details(calls) based on those parameters. Basically what you have in your main report, but rather than doing a COUNT on the #calls, simply return the details. 
Then in the main report:

Right click on the textbox, or link for #of Calls

Go to Properties, then Actions

Under enable as Actions, select "Go to report"

In the Specify Report drop, select your newly created call detail report.

Under the parameters section, add possibly the fields from your main report as Parameters, Loc and Tech.